# iOS: how to change Programmatically UI from LTR to RTL and viceversa

Tags: ios, iphone, user-interface, swift4, arabic

I need to change language from English to arabic. All UI's in app developed programatically, I didn't used storyboard/xib for UI. I used localization string for converting language, but I am looking for UI view from LTR to RTL and vice versa.

what is the best way for language change and give me some ideas or samples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the current language by this:

```
open class func isCurrentLanguageRTL(language:String) -> Bool {
        return Locale.characterDirection(forLanguage: language) == .rightToLeft
    }
```

**Use this objective C code(Category) you can change your UI RTL:**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface NSBundle (Language)

+ (void)setLanguage:(NSString *)language;

@end
```

**Implement file :**

```
#import "NSBundle+Language.h"
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <objc/runtime.h>

static const char kBundleKey = 0;

@interface BundleEx : NSBundle

@end

@implementation BundleEx

- (NSString *)localizedStringForKey:(NSString *)key value:(NSString *)value table:(NSString *)tableName
{
    NSBundle *bundle = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &kBundleKey);
    if (bundle) {
        return [bundle localizedStringForKey:key value:value table:tableName];
    }
    else {
        return [super localizedStringForKey:key value:value table:tableName];
    }
}

@end


@implementation NSBundle (Language)

+ (void)setLanguage:(NSString *)language
{
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        object_setClass([NSBundle mainBundle], [BundleEx class]);
    });
    if ([self isCurrentLanguageRTL:language]) {
        if ([[[UIView alloc] init] respondsToSelector:@selector(setSemanticContentAttribute:)]) {
            [[UIView appearance] setSemanticContentAttribute:UISemanticContentAttributeForceRightToLeft];
            [[UITableView appearance] setSemanticContentAttribute:UISemanticContentAttributeForceRightToLeft];
            [[UINavigationBar appearance] setSemanticContentAttribute:UISemanticContentAttributeForceRightToLeft];
        }
    }else {
        if ([[[UIView alloc] init] respondsToSelector:@selector(setSemanticContentAttribute:)]) {
            [[UIView appearance] setSemanticContentAttribute:UISemanticContentAttributeForceLeftToRight];
            [[UITableView appearance] setSemanticContentAttribute:UISemanticContentAttributeForceLeftToRight];
            [[UINavigationBar appearance] setSemanticContentAttribute:UISemanticContentAttributeForceLeftToRight];
        }
    }
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:[self isCurrentLanguageRTL:language] forKey:@"AppleTextDirection"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:[self isCurrentLanguageRTL:language] forKey:@"NSForceRightToLeftWritingDirection"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

    id value = language ? [NSBundle bundleWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:language ofType:@"lproj"]] : nil;
    objc_setAssociatedObject([NSBundle mainBundle], &kBundleKey, value, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}

+ (BOOL)isCurrentLanguageRTL:(NSString *)code
{
    return ([NSLocale characterDirectionForLanguage:code] == NSLocaleLanguageDirectionRightToLeft);
}
@end
```

**How to use:**

Any type of language(like RTL, LTR) only call this bundle function in your code:

```
Bundle.setLanguage(<#Your Language code#>)
```

**Note:** You should add the `#import "NSBundle+Language.h"` in your bridging Header file.

If you use the left menu than in case of RTL you have to open the menu from right just checking the above swift function like:

```
<#YourClass#>.isCurrentLanguageRTL(<#Your Language Code#>) {
  //open your side menu from right
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.. my doubt is directly we can add the above Objective-C class file in project right? I am working in swift4 .can you please send me a sample file or link using above code..it would be helpful for me and I will understand the scenario clearly.. please

Comment: Yes..Sure.. Please send your email Id, I can email you :) @RohithSingh

Comment: Thanks bro.. please send sample file to this mail id: rohith.qol@gmail.com

Comment: I will send you in the evening @RohithSingh

Comment: Bro., can you please send me mail., I'm waiting..@SaurabhJain

Comment: @RohithSingh Please check your inbox